# Math mode for csvsimple Import

Tags: tables, math-mode, csvsimple

I am currently struggling when I try to import a CSV file which contains math code using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % Math symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}  % Math formulas

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
ex1,\rho = 4e9
0,19.85
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{example.csv}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\rho` is not interpreted. Moreover, it does not even compile. I also tried `$\rho$` or within quotes.
Unfortunately, `csvsimple` does not seem to work along with math mode contents of the CSV. Does anybody has a solution for this?

Thank you in advance!
RMK

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the presence of macros in the first line of the file, which, according to the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple), is usually used to indicate the column identifiers. If you swap the lines (and insert `$` around `\rho`) the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for the fast anwer. You're right. Unfortunately, this is not what i want. I'd like to have `$\rho$` in the identifier line, as this is the parameter I am varying. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\csvautotabular` macro is just intended for raw viewing of text CSV files. For everything else, you should use `\csvreader` which allows full control of the content. If your file has no header, the assignment to the columns is simpy achieved by arabic numbers.

For following example sets the two columns in math mode and adds a line numbering for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % Math symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}  % Math formulas

% Make csv in question
\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
ex1,\rho = 4e9
0,19.85
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[no head,tabular=|l|c|c|,
  table head=\hline,late after line=\\\hline]{example.csv}
  {1=\one,2=\two}
  {\thecsvrow & $\one$ & $\two$}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is still cumbersome especially when I have various tables with various number of columns. However, I can work quite well with this snippet. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please, don't forget to press the `accept` button :-)